# PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)) error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  try {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
          apiKey: "apikey",
          appId: "appid",
          messagingSenderId: "fir-cli-2272f",
          projectId: "fir-cli-2272f"),
    );
    runApp(MyApp());
  } catch (e) {
    print('Hata: $e');
  }
}
```

> PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)) error

I changed the versions of firebase libraries, but it's not a solution.

- firebase_core: 2.25.4
- firebase_auth: 4.17.4

Comment: What platform are you running your Flutter app on?